# Change css where child element is on top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

a little bit stuck with some css. The problem is that I have some web page with DOM elements in there. And I have a task to set overlay div on top of everything and then by selecting some elements with the mouse, disable overlays opacity to be able to see the origin view of the page.

css:

```
div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.childDiv{
    position: absolute;
    border: tomato 1px solid;
}
```

After overlay appears on top of the page, by click I create new div with class 'childDiv' and append to overlay class.
So how should I change css (or even insert additional js functions) to get a clear view inside tomato bordered div?
[image]

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do , it will help you clarify your question before it gets closed ...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can think of creating an `absolute` `css grid` over the whole page whose cells will have the background: `rgba property (0,0,0,0.5)` and then add each of them in js functionality that will remove this background when clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (IMO) is to have the overlay use a `box-shadow` to create the overlay, and then you can just set the height/width of the overlay to be the window (and have it 0 when you don't want it).

Below will create an overlay, and when you click will create a "window" through the overlay where you clicked:

```js
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
window.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const {clientX, clientY} = event;
    overlay.style.height = '80px';
    overlay.style.width = '80px';
    overlay.style.left = (clientX - 40) + 'px';
    overlay.style.top = (clientY - 40) + 'px';
    overlay.style.border = 'tomato 1px solid';
});
```

```css
#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
<div id="overlay">
</div>
```